# TSTableView swift - "Unrecognized selector sent to instance XXXX"

Tags: ios, objective-c, swift, tableview

I am trying to set up a multi column table inside a Swift application using the library written in Obj C called TSUIKit which defines its own table TSTableView.

I have added the files to my project and to my bridging header and xcode recognizes correctly the classes...

Every time I execute the code, the tables shows the rows and columns correctly but when I touch any cell, an error appears which says the following:

```
2014-11-05 09:39:54.811 probarTabla[1584:20072] -[TSTableView numberOfColumns]: unrecognized selector sent to instance 0x7ffbc3654920
2014-11-05 09:39:54.937 probarTabla[1584:20072] *** Terminating app due to uncaught exception 'NSInvalidArgumentException', reason: '-[TSTableView numberOfColumns]: unrecognized selector sent to instance 0x7ffbc3654920'
*** First throw call stack:
```

Here is the code in the controller of the view, the test project only has a unique view with a TSTableView added which corresponds with "tabla" in the code of the ViewController

```
#import <Foundation/Foundation.h>
#import "TSTableView.h"
#import "TSTableViewDelegate.h"
#import "TSTableViewDataSource.h"
#import "TSTableViewHeaderSectionView.h"
#import "TSTableViewModel.h"
```

ViewController code:

```
import UIKit

class ViewController: UIViewController, TSTableViewDelegate {


    @IBOutlet var tabla: TSTableView!

    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()
        // Do any additional setup after loading the view, typically from a nib.
        tabla.delegate = self
        tabla.autoresizingMask = UIViewAutoresizing.FlexibleBottomMargin | UIViewAutoresizing.FlexibleWidth | UIViewAutoresizing.FlexibleHeight

        var pruebaColumna : NSArray = [
            ["title" : "Probando Columna 1"],
            ["title" : "Probando Columna 2"],
            ["title" : "Probando Columna 3"]
        ]

        var model : TSTableViewModel = TSTableViewModel(tableView: tabla, andStyle: kTSTableViewStyleDark)


        var pruebaFila : NSArray = [
            ["cells" : [
                ["value": "valor1"],
                ["value": "valor2"],
                ["value": "valor3"] 

                ]
            ]
        ]

        model.setColumns(pruebaColumna, andRows: pruebaFila)

    }

    override func didReceiveMemoryWarning() {
        super.didReceiveMemoryWarning()
        // Dispose of any resources that can be recreated.
    }

    func tableView(tableView: TSTableView!, didSelectRowAtPath rowPath: NSIndexPath!, selectedCell cellIndex: Int) {
        println("Has hecho click en la celda")
    }
}
```

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It is important you keep a strong refererence to your model, as this is the datasource.
Once you keep a strong reference to it, your problem will be solved.

Comment: Great ! Thanks for your help, once I added the TSTableView model as a controller var then it worked